# How to set different background according to one property?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I have `ListView` which `ItemSource` bindend to `ObservableCollection<Period>` where `Period` is

```
 public class Period : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    //some stuff
    //

    public Status PeriodStatus
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #region PropertyChangedEventHandler members

    public void SendPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion 
}

public enum Status
{
    None,
    Added,
    Deleted,
    Edited
}
```

And i want set background of each `ListViewItem` in this order : added-green/deleted-red/edited-yellow/none-default . Found at here many solutions, but didn't provide my solution. If there is exist question , please comment and i will close this

**[EDIT]**
I wanted to use `DataTemplate` in this way: create template which create binding with `Background` property and  `Status` in `Period` which uses converter. But didn't know how to keep rest of design

Comment: You can use `Converter` / `Style` & `Trigger` / `DataTemplate`.... What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `DataTrigger`s for the `Background` property in the `Style` of `ListViewItem` ([example in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488547/): you don't need the converter, use the enum values instead of integer values).

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodStatus}" Value="Added">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodStatus}" Value="Deleted">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodStatus}" Value="Edited">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            <Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one is to use `Triggers` in your `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodStatus}" Value="Added">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodStatus}" Value="Deleted">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PeriodStatus}" Value="Edited">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
        <Style.Triggers>
    <Style>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This is a sample code: you might need to add a namespace with your `enum` to use it in `XAML`.

Comment: I think it won't work. The style must be defined for `ListViewItem` (not `ListView` class).

Answer (score 0):

I find it more easy to have a dedicated PeriodStatusColor readonly property, less 'pure xaml', yes, but less code, and all code in the same place. So this property just returns color for current PeriodStatus. On PeriodStatus change, raise also a PeriodStatusColor PropertyChanged. Use static frozen color, and maybe use a PeriodStatus --> Color static Dictionnary to have clean code.